# Why did no one notice this character missing?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

In *The Shadow Rising*, we learn that

> the merchant Keille Shaogi is really Lanfear.

After that, they disappear, and no one says a word about it. Did people not notice? Or did Rand give a reason that they were gone that I didn't catch?

Comment: I vaguely recall someone mentioning that she left mysteriously, but you're right, I don't think that details about that were really given.

Answer (score 3):

This answer doesn't really satisfy me but we can draw some conclusions (however tenuous), from *Fires of Heaven*.

In chapter 29, *Memories of Saldaea*, we see from the POV of Hadnan Kadere that he doesn't seem to know either (obviously), but he has his theory:

> Nearly two months ago, right after Jasin Natael attached himself to Rand al'Thor [...] and his new partner Keille Shaogi had disappeared -- he suspected she was buried in the Waste, with a thrust from Natael's knife through her heart [...]

And in chapter 52, *Choices*, also from Kadere's point of view:

> "Aren't you going to look at an old friend, Hadnan?"
>
>  That melodious voice jerked Kadere around, gaping at a hatchet-nosed face, dark eyes almost hidden by rolls of fat. "Keille?" It was impossible. No one survived alone in the Waste except Aiel. She *had* to be dead. But there she stood, white silk straining over her bulk, ivory combs standing tall in her dark curls. [...]
>
>  He would as soon Keille Shaogi really had died in the Waste [...] but she stood as high as Jasin Natael. [...] At the least, he would have someone to work with. At the worst, someone to put blame on. [...] More than once he had fed his superiors to those still higher up in order to cover himself.

This quote seems to imply that everyone assumes she disappeared in the Waste and died. Since the two quotes have slightly different contents, I conclude that the latter indicates the "generally accepted story", while the former is Kadere's theory of "what *really* happened."

It's possible that this is addressed in one or another interview with Jordan/Sanderson but I am not sure how to search those efficiently.